# How will I dequeue the object that I enqueue from the other page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a Queue Management system right now in ASP.NET MVC

***1st scenario:***
customer will go to a laptop, enter their name and then confirm to receive the queue number, then the data will be save to the database.

I'm able to enqueue the incoming customer with this code.

```
    public static Queue<Queue> todayQueue = new Queue<Queue>();

    public ActionResult SetQueueInfo([Bind(Include = "QueueId,Name,QueueNumber,ServiceId,ServiceName,ServiceLetter")] Queue queue/*, int? id,string Name, string QueueNumber, string ServiceLetter, int ServiceId*/, int? id)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            todayQueue.Enqueue(queue);
            db.Queues.Add(queue);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View(queue);
        }

        return View();
    }
```

***2nd Scenario:***
the The Agent will click the "Next" button then I'm going to deQueue the data I enqueued in the first scenario.
I need to render the Dequeued data on my view when I click the "Next" Button.
can someone show me?, what am I missing?

```
    public ActionResult BtnNext()
    {
        var first = todayQueue.Dequeue();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

***note:***
customer page is different from agent's page, I need to dequeue the enqueued data and render to my agent's page.

Comment: are you using a database of some kind? if yes then you need to save data to it and fetch data from it.  learn how to do these things.

Comment: yes i have database, I just need to create a class and put static Queue<QueueTable> todayQueue in that class, can you show me how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the queue at the application level and enqueue and dequeue the data from that

So, your code would look something like this :

```
public ActionResult SetQueueInfo(MyData data)
{
    Queue<MyData> queue = null;

    if (Application["Queue"] != null)
    {
       queue = Application["Queue"] as Queue<MyData>;
    }
    else
    {
       queue = new Queue<MyData>();
    }

    queue.Enqueue(data);
    Application["Queue"] = queue;
    //other task you wanna do
}



public ActionResult BtnNext()
{
    var queue = Application["Queue"] as Queue<MyData>

    if(queue != null)
    {
        var first = queue.Dequeue();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```